# Unique itunes app keyword returns irrelevant results

Tags: app-store, itunes, keyword

This might not seem like a very critical question, as it affects a completely free and rather niche app, however there are some people affected and it just boggles my mind how it happens. Also, I tried asking on the Apple dev forums and I always get an "invalid character" no matter how much I strip out my post, so that perplexes me even more

Anyway, there is a not very well known weather service called "7timer", which is great for amateur astronomers as it has a forecast about astronomical seeing etc. It is a rather unique name, so if you search for the term say on google, everything you get is related to that service. There were a couple of iOS clients for it for a while, but they were gone by about 1-2 years ago, so I made a new free client for fellow astronomy hobbyists. It has had the modest downloads you would expect from it without any promotion really, as people searching for astro forecasts find it and use it. However, I was recently talking about weather apps with some people and they were very surprised to find out that there was a 7timer client for iOS, as they told me they had specifically searched for one on the app store and came up empty. And, sure enough, despite "7timer" being a keyword, being in the description of the app, inside the app etc, dozens of irrelevant results come up (from Casino apps, to sports games - with "7timer" appearing nowhere in their material) instead of the one actual client of the service. I had not tried the keywords before, so I don't know if it was like that from the start.

I wrote to Apple dev support and they told me that the other apps just come up higher than mine in that keyword search. I wrote again and said that for those apps to come higher, it means they either have it as a keyword (which I don't think it is allowed, as it is not relevant), or they don't and there is a bug with the search. Apple responded that their proprietary algorithm does not look only at keywords, and it is working fine thank-you-very-much.

As I said, it is not a big deal, there is no revenue involved, and most people do find it (i.e. unless they search specifically for that weather service - which of course might mean the people who'd want it the most), but, really, how can it happen? Does the app-store search go completely bonkers often and I just haven't noticed? I mean, it is not even a desirable search term which you would try to put in your keywords (or pay to rank in it), so I can't think of a rational explanation.
TIA

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't a programming question and I don't think it's answerable by anyone except Apple. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Comment: I actually did not know if we handled non-programming questions here, so I did a quick search before posting to check and saw there were other questions about itunes keywords, so I assumed it was fine. But I don't have a problem closing it, if it turns out those other questions should not have been posted either...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Apple App Store search ranking issues instead of directly about programming or coding.